# converting from treebank tags to wordnet-compatible tags in Java?

Tags: java, nlp

I have POS tagged input from OpenNLP...i need to use these with WordNet...but wordnet uses only 4 tags - noun, verb, adjective, adverb...where OpenNLP generates tags based on  [Penn treebank tagset](http://www.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/projekte/CorpusWorkbench/CQP-HTMLDemo/PennTreebankTS.html) . I need to convert them to wordnet-compatible tags... i did find  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364493/lemmatizing-pos-tagged-words-with-nltk)  on the site - but its all python..i need java

agreed that i can write a simple function myself to rename these tags..but what to do with other tags like DT, PP, PDT, POS, MD, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Some more information about what you're wanting to do with WordNet associations might be helpful, but my first guess is that you want to discard parts-of-speech which don't map cleanly to the WordNet categories.

For example, consider DT (determiner). Are you hoping to get a relationship between, say, 'the' and 'an' from WordNet? Similarly, there might be useful relationships in WordNet for PP (prepositions), but I suspect you're much more likely to find helpful relationships between different nouns or verbs than between closed-class words.

My recommendation is to start by mapping each of the TreeBank part-of-speech tags to one of the WordNet classes, or to 'null' for those parts-of-speech that don't have obvious mappings (you could probably find such a mapping somewhere, but with only 36 tags, it might be just as easy to do yourself).

For closed-class words, you might decide to use another source of relationship metadata, but that will probably depend on the end-goal of your application.

Comment: i have said it all in my question..of course i can map manually and then write a function for it...but won't if affect my application? I am trying to extract synsets from wordnet?? what operation will I do on words which will have null tags after the working the mapping fucntion?? how will i process these non-wordnet tags?? that is the main question...

Comment: What is your application? Extracting synsets from WordNet isn't usually an end-goal. What sort of mapping would you like to find for 'an', for example? I'm not anything close to an expert on WordNet, but I wouldn't expect to find synonyms of antonyms for 'an', 'the', 'of', etc. The concept of synonym and antonym doesn't make much sense for closed-class words.