# wordnet lemmatization and pos tagging in python

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet, lemmatization

I wanted to use wordnet lemmatizer in python and I have learnt that the default pos tag is NOUN and that it does not output the correct lemma for a verb, unless the pos tag is explicitly specified as VERB.

My question is what is the best shot inorder to perform the above lemmatization accurately?

I did the pos tagging using `nltk.pos_tag` and I am lost in integrating the tree bank pos tags to wordnet compatible pos tags. Please help

```
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
```

I get the output tags in NN,JJ,VB,RB. How do I change these to wordnet compatible tags?

Also do I have to train `nltk.pos_tag()` with a tagged corpus or can I use it directly on my data to evaluate?

Comment: very good question indeed!

Answer (score 98, accepted):

First of all, you can use `nltk.pos_tag()` directly without training it. 
The function will load a pretrained tagger from a file. You can see the file name 
with `nltk.tag._POS_TAGGER`:

```
nltk.tag._POS_TAGGER
>>> 'taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle'
```

As it was trained with the Treebank corpus, it also uses the [Treebank tag set](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html).

The following function would map the treebank tags to WordNet part of speech names:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

def get_wordnet_pos(treebank_tag):

    if treebank_tag.startswith('J'):
        return wordnet.ADJ
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('V'):
        return wordnet.VERB
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('N'):
        return wordnet.NOUN
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('R'):
        return wordnet.ADV
    else:
        return ''
```

You can then use the return value with the lemmatizer:

```
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
lemmatizer.lemmatize('going', wordnet.VERB)
>>> 'go'
```

Check the return value before passing it to the Lemmatizer because an empty string would give a `KeyError`.

Comment: remember also satellite adjectives =) `ADJ_SAT = 's'` http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/man/wngloss.7WN.html

Comment: the pos tag for `'it'` in the `"I'm loving it."` string is `'PRP'`. The function returns an empty string which the lemmatizer doesn't accept and throws a `KeyError`. What can be done in that case?

Comment: Does anyone know how efficient this is when processing entire documents?

Comment: I would rather use something like... treebank_tag[0].lower()  as input for the lemmatizer pos-tag. In most cases this covers the conversion, except with the ADJ. But this can then be a simple if statement

Comment: @ClockSlave: Don't put empty strings into the lemmatizer.

Comment: @alvas Which treebank tags should be mapped to the ADJ_SAT WordNet tag?

Comment: 'RP' starts with 'R'. But it is a particle. Is the 'particle' to 'ADV' reasonable?

Answer (score 15):

> Steps to convert : **Document->Sentences->Tokens->POS->Lemmas**

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

#example text text = 'What can I say about this place. The staff of these restaurants is nice and the eggplant is not bad'

class Splitter(object):
    """
    split the document into sentences and tokenize each sentence
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.splitter = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
        self.tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.TreebankWordTokenizer()

    def split(self,text):
        """
        out : ['What', 'can', 'I', 'say', 'about', 'this', 'place', '.']
        """
        # split into single sentence
        sentences = self.splitter.tokenize(text)
        # tokenization in each sentences
        tokens = [self.tokenizer.tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences]
        return tokens


class LemmatizationWithPOSTagger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def get_wordnet_pos(self,treebank_tag):
        """
        return WORDNET POS compliance to WORDENT lemmatization (a,n,r,v) 
        """
        if treebank_tag.startswith('J'):
            return wordnet.ADJ
        elif treebank_tag.startswith('V'):
            return wordnet.VERB
        elif treebank_tag.startswith('N'):
            return wordnet.NOUN
        elif treebank_tag.startswith('R'):
            return wordnet.ADV
        else:
            # As default pos in lemmatization is Noun
            return wordnet.NOUN

    def pos_tag(self,tokens):
        # find the pos tagginf for each tokens [('What', 'WP'), ('can', 'MD'), ('I', 'PRP') ....
        pos_tokens = [nltk.pos_tag(token) for token in tokens]

        # lemmatization using pos tagg   
        # convert into feature set of [('What', 'What', ['WP']), ('can', 'can', ['MD']), ... ie [original WORD, Lemmatized word, POS tag]
        pos_tokens = [ [(word, lemmatizer.lemmatize(word,self.get_wordnet_pos(pos_tag)), [pos_tag]) for (word,pos_tag) in pos] for pos in pos_tokens]
        return pos_tokens

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
splitter = Splitter()
lemmatization_using_pos_tagger = LemmatizationWithPOSTagger()

#step 1 split document into sentence followed by tokenization
tokens = splitter.split(text)

#step 2 lemmatization using pos tagger 
lemma_pos_token = lemmatization_using_pos_tagger.pos_tag(tokens)
print(lemma_pos_token)
```

Answer (score 12):

As in the source code of nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet (http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.html)

```
#{ Part-of-speech constants
 ADJ, ADJ_SAT, ADV, NOUN, VERB = 'a', 's', 'r', 'n', 'v'
#}
POS_LIST = [NOUN, VERB, ADJ, ADV]
```

Comment: Or more generally:

from nltk.corpus import wordnet;
print wordnet._FILEMAP;

Comment: Why is ADJ_SAT not represented in the POST_LIST? What are examples for ADJ_SAT adjectives?

Comment: ADJ_SAT falls under Adjective cluster. You can read more about how adjective clusters are arranged here: https://wordnet.princeton.edu/documentation/wngloss7wn

Answer (score 9):

You can create a map using the python default dict and take advantage of the fact that for the lemmatizer the default tag is Noun.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
from collections import defaultdict

tag_map = defaultdict(lambda : wn.NOUN)
tag_map['J'] = wn.ADJ
tag_map['V'] = wn.VERB
tag_map['R'] = wn.ADV

text = "Another way of achieving this task"
tokens = word_tokenize(text)
lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()

for token, tag in pos_tag(tokens):
    lemma = lmtzr.lemmatize(token, tag_map[tag[0]])
    print(token, "=>", lemma)
```

Comment: to make this answer self-contained, remember import wn:
`from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn`

Comment: @pragMATHiC, included it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

@Suzana_K was working. But I there are some case result in KeyError as @ Clock Slave mention.

Convert treebank tags to Wordnet tag

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

def get_wordnet_pos(treebank_tag):

    if treebank_tag.startswith('J'):
        return wordnet.ADJ
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('V'):
        return wordnet.VERB
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('N'):
        return wordnet.NOUN
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('R'):
        return wordnet.ADV
    else:
        return None # for easy if-statement
```

Now, we only input pos into lemmatize function only if we have wordnet tag

```
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
for word, tag in tagged:
    wntag = get_wordnet_pos(tag)
    if wntag is None:# not supply tag in case of None
        lemma = lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) 
    else:
        lemma = lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, pos=wntag)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do as following:

```py
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

wordnet_map = {
    "N": wordnet.NOUN,
    "V": wordnet.VERB,
    "J": wordnet.ADJ,
    "R": wordnet.ADV
}


def pos_tag_wordnet(text):
    """
        Create pos_tag with wordnet format
    """
    pos_tagged_text = nltk.pos_tag(text)

    # map the pos tagging output with wordnet output
    pos_tagged_text = [
        (word, wordnet_map.get(pos_tag[0])) if pos_tag[0] in wordnet_map.keys()
        else (word, wordnet.NOUN)
        for (word, pos_tag) in pos_tagged_text
    ]

    return pos_tagged_text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line:

```
wnpos = lambda e: ('a' if e[0].lower() == 'j' else e[0].lower()) if e[0].lower() in ['n', 'r', 'v'] else 'n'
```

Then use `wnpos(nltk_pos)` to get the POS to give to .lemmatize().  In your case, `lmtzr.lemmatize(word=tagged[0][0], pos=wnpos(tagged[0][1]))`.

Answer (score 0):

After searching from internet, I've found this solution: from sentence to "bag of words" derived after splitting, pos_tagging, lemmatizing and cleaning (from punctuation and "stopping words") operations.
Here's my code:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from nltk.wsd import lesk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer 
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

punctuation = u",.?!()-_\"\'\\\n\r\t;:+*<>@#§^$%&|/"
stop_words_eng = set(stopwords.words('english'))
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
tag_dict = {"J": wn.ADJ,
            "N": wn.NOUN,
            "V": wn.VERB,
            "R": wn.ADV}

def extract_wnpostag_from_postag(tag):
    #take the first letter of the tag
    #the second parameter is an "optional" in case of missing key in the dictionary 
    return tag_dict.get(tag[0].upper(), None)

def lemmatize_tupla_word_postag(tupla):
    """
    giving a tupla of the form (wordString, posTagString) like ('guitar', 'NN'), return the lemmatized word
    """
    tag = extract_wnpostag_from_postag(tupla[1])    
    return lemmatizer.lemmatize(tupla[0], tag) if tag is not None else tupla[0]

def bag_of_words(sentence, stop_words=None):
    if stop_words is None:
        stop_words = stop_words_eng
    original_words = word_tokenize(sentence)
    tagged_words = nltk.pos_tag(original_words) #returns a list of tuples: (word, tagString) like ('And', 'CC')
    original_words = None
    lemmatized_words = [ lemmatize_tupla_word_postag(ow) for ow in tagged_words ]
    tagged_words = None
    cleaned_words = [ w for w in lemmatized_words if (w not in punctuation) and (w not in stop_words) ]
    lemmatized_words = None
    return cleaned_words

sentence = "Two electric guitar rocks players, and also a better bass player, are standing off to two sides reading corpora while walking"
print(sentence, "\n\n bag of words:\n", bag_of_words(sentence) )
```