# Lemmainser using NLTK

Tags: python, text, nltk, text-processing

I currently have a sentence like this:

```
text = "This is a car."
```

I then use a tokeniser and then stem it like so:

```
ps = PorterStemmer()
text = word_tokenize(text)
stemmed_words = []
for w in words:
    stemmed_words.append(ps.stem(w))
```

However, I now wish to use NLTK's lemmainser to do this instead. To use it, I need to give it the parts-of-speach of the word like so (inside the loop):

```
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
word = lemmatizer.lemmatize(w, pos=pos)
```

However, I am unsure how to get the pos argument. I understand I can use this to get the part of speach but that is not accepted as an argument:

```
pos = nltk.pos_tag(text)
```

Comment: `WordNetLemmatizer` does not need the second parameter. Most of the time it works perfectly fine with just the word that you try to lemmatize.

Comment: @DYZ I understand this, but am hoping that using this will improve it.

Comment: Then your answer has been already partially answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586721/wordnet-lemmatization-and-pos-tagging-in-python

Comment: Possibly you want something like this: https://gist.github.com/alvations/07758d02412d928414bb . Originally from https://github.com/alvations/pywsd/blob/master/pywsd/utils.py#L66

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a dictionary to to translate NLTK POS tags into WordNet tags:

```
pos_translate = {'J':'a', 'V':'v', 'N':'n', 'R':'r'}
```

Now, extract POS tags, translate each tag, if possible (if not, choose a default tag, say, `"n"`, and lemmatize:

```
text = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'car', '.']
[lemmatizer.lemmatize(w,\
       pos=pos_translate[pos[0]] if pos[0] in pos_translate else 'n')\
       for w,pos in nltk.pos_tag(text)]
# ['This', 'be', 'a', 'car', '.']
```