# Convert Averaged Perceptron Tagger POS to WordNet POS and Avoid Tuple Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I have code for POS tagging with NLTK's averaged perceptron tagger:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk import pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

string = 'dogs runs fast'

tokens = word_tokenize(string)
tokensPOS = pos_tag(tokens)
print(tokensPOS)
```

Result:

```
[('dogs', 'NNS'), ('runs', 'VBZ'), ('fast', 'RB')]
```

I have attempted code for looping through each tagged token and lemmatizing it with the WordNet lemmatizer:

```
lemmatizedWords = []
for w in tokensPOS:
       lemmatizedWords.append(WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(w))

print(lemmatizedWords)
```

Resulting Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-30-462d7c3bdbb7>", line 15, in <module>
    lemmatizedWords = WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(w)

  File "C:\Users\taca\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\stem\wordnet.py", line 40, in lemmatize
    lemmas = wordnet._morphy(word, pos)

  File "C:\Users\taca\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py", line 1712, in _morphy
    forms = apply_rules([form])

  File "C:\Users\taca\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py", line 1692, in apply_rules
    for form in forms

  File "C:\Users\taca\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py", line 1694, in <listcomp>
    if form.endswith(old)]

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

I think I have two problems here:

1. The POS tags are not converted to tags WordNet can understand (I tried implementing something similar to this answer [wordnet lemmatization and pos tagging in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586721/wordnet-lemmatization-and-pos-tagging-in-python) with no success)
2. The data structures are not correctly formed to be able to loop through each tuple (I couldn't find much on this error beyond `os` related code)

How do I follow up POS tagging with lemmatization to avoid these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python interpreter clearly told You:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

`tokensPOS` is an array of tuples, so You can't pass its elements directly to `lemmatize()` method (look at code of class `WordNetLemmatizer` [here](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/stem/wordnet.html)). Only string type object have method `endswith()`, so You need to pass first element of every tuple from `tokenPOS`, just like that:

```
lemmatizedWords = []
for w in tokensPOS:
    lemmatizedWords.append(WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(w[0]))
```

Method `lemmatize()` uses `wordnet.NOUN` as a default POS. Unfortunately Wordnet uses different tags than other nltk corpora, so You have to manually translate them (as in the link You provided) and use proper tag as a second parameter to `lemmatize()`. Full script, with method `get_wordnet_pos()` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15590384/4088548):

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk import pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

def get_wordnet_pos(treebank_tag):

    if treebank_tag.startswith('J'):
        return wordnet.ADJ
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('V'):
        return wordnet.VERB
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('N'):
        return wordnet.NOUN
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('R'):
        return wordnet.ADV
    else:
        return ''

string = 'dogs runs fast'

tokens = word_tokenize(string)
tokensPOS = pos_tag(tokens)
print(tokensPOS)

lemmatizedWords = []
for w in tokensPOS:
    lemmatizedWords.append(WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(w[0],get_wordnet_pos(w[1])))

print(lemmatizedWords)
```

Comment: That works to remove the tuple error - thanks. But the lemmatizer is still defaulting to nouns, right? How would I convert from the averaged perceptron tagger tags to WordNet tags?

Comment: @CameronTaylor I've upgraded my answer - hope it helps.

Comment: Right, so that works with the treebank model. I'm looking for the conversion between the averaged perceptron model and WordNet. I'm just not sure where to start in that regard. For example, what is the averaged perceptron equivalent of `treebank_tag`?

Comment: @CameronTaylor Averaged perceptron uses treebank model tags: https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html