# Using WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize() with pos_tags throws KeyError

Tags: python, text, nlp, nltk, lemmatization

I just read that lemmatization results are best when assisted with pos_tags. Hence I followed the below code but getting KeyError for calculated POS_tags. Below is the code

```
   from nltk import pos_tag
   x['Phrase']=x['Phrase'].transform(lambda value:value.lower())
   x['Phrase']=x['Phrase'].transform(lambda value:pos_tag(value))
```

Output after 3rd line (after calculating POS Tags)
[image]

```
   from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer 
   lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
   x['Phrase_lemma']=x['Phrase'].transform(lambda value: ' '.join([lemmatizer.lemmatize(a[0],pos=a[1]) for a in  value]))
```

Error:

```
 KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-8-c2400a79a016> in <module>
  1 from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
  2 lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
  ----> 3 x['Phrase_lemma']=x['Phrase'].transform(lambda value: ' '.join([lemmatizer.lemmatize(a[0],pos=a[1]) for a in  value]))

 KeyError: 'DT'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a `KeyError` because `wordnet` is not using the same `pos` labels. The accepted `pos` labels for `wordnet` based on [source code](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/6404712d0a64c3d6e3700032c23a59803615460c/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L1076) are these: `adj`, `adv`, `adv` and `verb`.

**EDIT** based on @bivouac0 's comment:

So to bypass this issue you have to make a mapper. Mapping function is heavily based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15590384/6779252). Non-supported POS will not be lemmatized.

```py
import nltk
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer 

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def get_wordnet_pos(treebank_tag):
    if treebank_tag.startswith('J'):
        return wordnet.ADJ
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('V'):
        return wordnet.VERB
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('N'):
        return wordnet.NOUN
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('R'):
        return wordnet.ADV
    else:
        return None

x = pd.DataFrame(data=[['this is a sample of text.'], ['one more text.']], 
                 columns=['Phrase'])

x['Phrase'] = x['Phrase'].apply(lambda v: nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(v)))


x['Phrase_lemma'] = x['Phrase'].transform(lambda value: ' '.join([lemmatizer.lemmatize(a[0],pos=get_wordnet_pos(a[1])) if get_wordnet_pos(a[1]) else a[0] for a in  value]))
```

Comment: But what should I do with other tags like DT? I think there exists no mapping for it in wordnet.

Comment: well I believe that you have to make the assumption that everything else will be considered as `NOUN`.

Comment: But won't this be incorrect? can you provide me a trusted source where you read this? that would be a great help

Comment: The previous comment was based on the default `pos` value of [`WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html#nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer.lemmatize) method. I can't support it from linguistic perspective. Another alternative could be to not lemmatize non-supported POS.

Comment: Only verbs, adj/adv and nouns have have lemma. Things like DT (determiners, ie.. a, an, the) don't have lemma. Don't try to lemmatize other tags by telingl Wordnet they're nouns.  You might get incorrect/odd results.  The only exception to this I can think of is POS=MD is a type of verb so anything tagged `MD` should probably lemmatize with the verbs.